# Dropbox web-client drag-drop from file-system

Tags: windows-7, dropbox, drag-and-drop

With the personal edition version that is installed on my Windows 7 computer, when dragging a file from the file system to a Dropbox folder in the web browser, a file already in the Dropbox folder with the same name gets overwritten.

Is there  a setting somewhere that will cause the Dropbox web-client to append `(1)` or `(2)` etc. to the filename, so that the original file can be retained, or that will present a dialog which gives the user a choice how to handle the situation:

```
Abandon the copy operation
Overwrite the original
Rename the copy with a numerical suffix
```

Is that feature available in the Business version if not in the personal edition?

Comment: By browser you mean web browser?

Comment: Yes, the web-browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is the current behavior of Dropbox. In past versions, adding folders via Dropbox web would rename the folders names. Now, the default behavior is to merge and overwrite all matching files (case insensitive at least from Windows).